# Focus stacking images using feature matching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to build a code using python where I am trying to align multiple images at least 10 with a reference image. All the images are taken on a smartphone camera. I have come across several documentation which does this for 2 images. But can not find any for multiple images. Can any suggest something which might be helpful. The link to the documentation I mentioned earlier is: https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/. This is what I have tried to iterate through the images. What I expect at the end is that an aligned image from the all the images should be output.

```
 # Read reference image
  refFilename = "images/image12.jpg"
  print("Reading reference image : ", refFilename)
  imReference = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

   #Load all the images
  all_images_to_compare=[]  
  all_images = glob.iglob("images/*.jpg")
  for images in all_images:
    imFilename =cv2.imread(images)
    all_images_to_compare.append(imFilename)





  for images_to_compare in all_images_to_compare: 
  #imFilename = cv_image
  #print("Reading image to align : ", imFilename);  
  #im = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

      print("Aligning images ...")
      # Registered image will be resotred in imReg. 
      # The estimated homography will be stored in h. 
      imReg, h = alignImages(images_to_compare, imReference)

      # Write aligned image to disk. 
      outFilename = "aligned.jpg"
      print("Saving aligned image : ", outFilename); 
      cv2.imwrite(outFilename, imReg)

      # Print estimated homography
      print("Estimated homography : \n",  h)
```

Comment: Please provide some example images, and the desired output, e.g. put together manually in GIMP or something else. From your question, I'd assume, you want to do some kind of [image stitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching), i.e. generating "panoramas"!? [Focus stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stacking) as mentioned in the title is something (totally) different.

Comment: @HansHirse you are right something as produced in GIMP. I am trying to get the exact output as given by GIMP. But I am not able to implement that using opencv. Can you suggest how to obtain the desired output(as using GIMP) through opencv. Thanks in advance.